# Datatable button filter with range search

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have buttons of range like `0-70%,70-85%,85%+`(with check box behavior). when user clicks on this button. It hides rows which don't follow filtered criteria. here I have 12 tables in page and i want to make this filter for specific tables. I searched for this but it gives me range filter, which will not solve my purpose. Any idea how to do this?

DataTable is like:

```
Student Name  Score Time taken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the answer. Here i made status for each range 0-70% stored as PP(data-search=PP), 70-85% stored as P, 85%+ stored as A. Then i used fnFilter with usage of RE.

```
var $tbl = $(this).dataTable();
allowedScore = ["P","AP"].join("|")
$tbl.fnFilter( "^("+allowedScore+")$",colIndex,true,true);
```

This will work as range filter and or operation between multiple range.